# add character to its pointer from another string array by only their pointers [C language]

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

How to add character to its pointer from another string array by only their pointers. Here I'm trying to copy character by character (by For Loop) to empty 'copy' array from 'buffer' array by using their defined pointers. And get output 'stop' from 'buffer' by 'copy' array or 'copy_ptr' pointer.

```
char buffer[5] = "stop";    // Buffer character array
char copy[5];               // Copy character empty array

// Pointers
char *buffer_ptr, *copy_ptr;

buffer_ptr = buffer;   // Pointing to buffer array
copy_ptr = copy;       // Pointing to copy array

// Loop for character by character storing in copy array
// by prointer
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++)   
{
    copy_ptr = buffer[i];
    copy_ptr = copy_ptr + 1;
}

puts(result); 
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Dereference `copy_ptr` first, before assigning the element it is pointing to.  `*copy_ptr = buffer[i];`

Comment: You meant:  `*copy_ptr = buffer[i]`  Also, you've rewritten a function called `memcpy`, and probably meant to use the function `strcpy`.

Comment: @SUD pythonism  Why are you ignoring my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72733182/add-element-by-element-in-array-pointer-from-buffer-pointer-in-for-loop/72734343#72734343?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Nope But actually I didn't understood function for ( char *buffer_ptr = buffer, *copy_ptr = copy; ( *copy_ptr++ = *buffer_ptr++ ) != '\0'; );             I'm Beginner so please can you explain me these function ?

Comment: @SUDpythonism Then write a comment to my answer saying what is unclear.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I got it now, Thanks